# Selecting cells shows count, not sum

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2000

I have a PC with Excel 2000 and when I select the numbers from some cells, it shows in the status bar the **Count** of the cells. I need to make it to show the **Sum** of that cells.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In Excel 2000/2007/2010**:

Right clicking the status bar where you have **Count** currently should give you a context menu to select **Sum**.

---

**Source**:

http://excel.tips.net/T005491_Status_Bar_Summing_No_Longer_Available.html

Answer (score -1):

This could also be the way the text is stored.  If it's stored as text and not a number the sum will not calculate.  You should be seeing an exclamation point to show this error. Highlight all of the column, select the exclamation point and convert to number.  This will then show the calculation in bar.